# Create custom SELinux file context/type from CIL

Tags: selinux

I'd like to create a new context from my SELinux module (written using the CIL syntax) that will then beu sed for my application's log file so logrotate can access it. However, when I try to `semodule -i` a file with the following contents:

```
(type indico_log_t)
(typeattributeset file_type (indico_log_t))
(typeattributeset logfile (indico_log_t))

(filecon "/opt/indico/log/.*\.log" any (system_u object_r indico_log_t ((s0)(s0))))
```

I get this error:

```
Type indico_log_t is invalid for role object_r
Invalid context
Invalid filecon at /etc/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/400/indico-new/cil:5
Failed to verify cil database
Failed to verify cil database
semodule:  Failed!
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a different way of creating a new type that can be used for a file?

FWIW, if I remove the last line I can install the module, but `chcon` doesn't accept the type (`chcon: invalid context: indico_log_t`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use roletype to allow a type to be associate with a role.

```
(roletype object_r indico_log_t)
```

Comment: Indeed, that solved it. Someone in #selinux on IRC had suggested the same and it worked fine, but I had completely forgotten about this question here.